# How to add new data without overwriting existing data with read_excel and to_excel using Pandas

Tags: excel, pandas, openpyxl, overwrite, xlsxwriter

I have sliced some dataframe from an existing excel file and I want to write this data to a new Excel file (called "model.xlsx" in my example below). I want the excel equivalent of to_csv("file.csv", "a") whereby you can keep on writing data to that same file(model.xlsx) and it will not erase the existing data. If the 'a' option is not available for excel, how do I write to a new sheet without erasing the existing sheet? I tried the openpyxl solution but it doesnt work for me.

```
import pandas as pd
file='ali.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name="IS", encode="UTF-8")
items=df.iloc[:,0:1]
angka=df.iloc[:,2:9]
angka.columns =['Mar2010','Mar2011','Mar2012','Mar2013','Mar2014','Mar2015','Mar2016']
df1=pd.concat([items, angka],axis=1)
df1.to_excel('model.xlsx', 'IS', index=False, header=True)
```

the code I used when trying out the openpyxl solution suggested doesn't work. Can you please give a suggestion?

If we have to use openpyxl how do I reference to the sheet I want to activate?
I have tried the myworkbook.Sheet("Sheet1").Activate command but it says 'Workbook object has no attribute 'sheets'.

Comment: An easy workaround to that is to create a new DataFrame that contains both the excel file and the sliced DataFrame and then save this to Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That would be easy but quite inefficient

Comment: Another workaround for it would be to save in the `.csv` file and then convert csv to excel. That could be actually somewhat fast.

Comment: agreed, im actually gonna do that. csv is so much simpler to process...

Comment: CSV has its own problems. openpyxl will let you add a dataframe to an existing worksheet.